# JavaScript is not function properly when set it locally

Tags: javascript, java, web

I want to import `raphael-min.js` for my jsp. I'm using

`<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.2/raphael-min.js"></script>`

tag for importing of the script. But the I want to include this js locally because when rendering this script is blocked by the browser. I copy the code from the url above and save it as a js file. and include as this

`<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/raphael/raphael-min.js"></script>`.

But the problem is js is not function at all. Are there any method to download this and include in jsp file?

Comment: Have you tried downloading through their github? [https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/releases]

Comment: Tried this all well. But the issue is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

We may load js file adding script tag in DOM:
Try the below code:

```
   var script = document.createElement('script');           
    script.src = PATH;
    script.onload =  function(){
        FILE LOADED           
    };
    document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems weird that a browser is blocking a cloudflare.com URL - are you using AdBlock or similar extensions? Try accessing the page through incognito or private browsing mode (assuming that the extension is disabled - the default - in that mode) for Chrome and Firefox respectively.

If you are seeing a particular error message, please post the error message - it will probably give clues as to why it is being blocked.

P.S: I would've posted a comment if my reputation allowed it. If you post clarifications, I can edit this answer accordingly.